# How to compile fla to swf

Tags: actionscript, adobe, flash, fla

I tried to compile fla and ac to *.swf, but just the *.fla file is compiled not ActionScripts *.ac.

Im using Adobe Flash CS6. How can i Compile the file as a Perfect Swf File?

Comment: Are you sure it's ".ac" not ".as"?

Comment: yeah buddy its .as   i forgot

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are expecting AS files to be generated when compiling an FLA file?

Inside whichever file path you have defined in "Publish Settings", you should be getting an SWF file (and whichever other kind of output file you have defined).

But AS files cannot be generated from compiling. All scripts you externally use inside the FLA's library will stay the same. AS files can only be written/generated by the user.